# Removing directory and it's contents with %Y_%b_%d format

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, timestamps, tmp

I have created a script which should delete the directories and it's contents older then 2 days.
The script is working fine but the directory is not getting deleted. 
Kindly help, it will be much appreciated.

## Script details:

```
export BACKUP_SETS=/backupset/
if [ ! -d "$BACKUP_SETS" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
  printf "\nFailure when removing BACKUP_SETS, Exiting \n"
  exit 1
 else
        two_days=$(date -d "2 days ago" +%Y_%b_%d)
                for f in $BACKUP_SETS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
                [ -d "$f" ] || continue
                (( $f < $two_days )) && echo rm -r "$f"
                done
       printf "\n BACKUP_SETS was removed successfully.\n"

fi
```

The directory contains folder as mentioned below.

```
[oracle@ backupset]$ ls -lrt
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba 12288 Jul 23 18:32 2018_Aug_23
```

## Output of the script:

```
[oracle@ backupset]$ ./backupset.sh

 BACKUP_SETS was removed successfully.
```

Comment: You’re echoing the rm command instead of calling it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller there's no `rm -f ...` written in the sample run, though

Comment: That’s a very good point; the script doesn’t match the output...

Comment: Also very funny: beginning of february,, you will remove files that are recent too, since "2019 Feb ..."  is smaller than "2019 Jan ...".

Answer (score 3):

Your `$BACKUP_SETS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` wildcard does not match your directory name `2018_Aug_23`.

You should name your directory `20180823` instead, then it will be seen by your script. Also, named months do not compare correctly (`Apr` < `Mar`).

To make the directory name better readable, you could name your directories like `2018-08-23` and use the wildcard `$BACKUP_SETS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
find "$BACKUP_SETS" -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find "$BACKUP_SETS" -type d -mindepth 1 -mtime +2 -exec rmdir {} \;
```

The directories will be removed a couple of days later than their latest file.

Comment: @roaima  Don't know if the OP needs it, but this find will not try to remove a higher directory in which a lower one has recently been removed.  There will be errors when trying to remove a directory with subs when nothing was changed for two days (unlikely), but no harm will be done.

Comment: And the `-depth` qualifier will stop it generating those errors. As you say, no harm done, though.

Comment: You think so?   You should try it, replacing mtime by mmin (unless you're very patient)..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you cannot use `<` to compare month names:

```
(( '2018-Aug-29' < '2018-Feb-28' )) && echo 'Uh oh, August is before February' || echo 'Sanity prevails'
Uh oh, August is before February
```

If you want to compare date strings lexically I would suggest you use YYYY-MM-DD format.

Better though, might be to use `find` to delete older directories regardless of the naming convention:

```
find "$BACKUP_SETS" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +2 -print -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

Needless to say, remove the `echo` when you want it to run for real.

Comment: I wanted that my script should run, but i got the concept why it is not deleting the directory.
Thanks everyone for the quick reply.